# Milk quantity and consistency in cortado, cappuccino and latte

Tags: cappuccino, latte, milk

I am often asked whether these three drinks have the same milk quantity and/or consistency and where the difference really lies between these preparations.

I would assume that quantity is increased respectively (cortado < cappuccino < latte) but some claim that there is more milk in the cortado than the cappuccino.

As for the consistency, wouldn't the cappuccino have a more foamy milk than the other two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There's a chart for that!**

Here's a [link](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0211/4926/files/PopChartLab__Expresso_Large506.jpg?1290) to it, but I've also included an image below.

There could be some argument over cappuccino vs. latte as to which is "creamier" as the cappuccino certainly has more mil foam, but the latte has much more milk by volume and by ratio. On the whole though I'd say the latte is a less strong drink with a creamier texture even if the cappuccino is thicker.

[image: espresso based beverage chart]

Comment: The "Strong"-ness of these drinks is arguable since they all have the same number of espresso shots so one could state that they are equally "strong" but the chart is very informative for the milk quantity and consistency!

Answer (score 0):

strength of an equal part espresso shot diluted changes the outcome of strength no? I would argue the least diluted drink is strongest (holding espresso amount the same.)

Comment: I think the question was about milk quantity as opposed to espresso and caffeine.